# how to display an element based on presence of a user token

Tags: reactjs, flask

I'm trying to make a website like Reddit now. I'd like to display "Log out" in the dropdown menu when a user logged in and "Log In / Sign up" when a user isn't. The user authentication part works fine. The problem is that token state doesn't change in the Navbar component. I know something's wrong with my use of useEffect but I'm not sure how to fix.

server.py

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        if isEmail(data['email']):
            email = data['email']
        else:
            print('Not a valid email')
            return "Register Failed"
        username = data['username']
        password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
            data['password']).decode('utf-8')
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(email, username, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                    (email, username, password))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()

        new_user = {
            'email': email,
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        }

        return jsonify(new_user=new_user)
    return "Register Success"


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        result = ""
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{0}'".format(username))
        rv = cur.fetchone()

        if not rv:
            print("Username does not exist")
        else:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(rv['password'], password):
                access_token = create_access_token(
                    identity={'username': rv['username']})
                result = jsonify(access_token=access_token)
            else:
                print("Invalid Password")
                result = jsonify(error_message="Invalid Password")
            return result
    return "Login Page"
```

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.usetoken) {
      setToken(localStorage.usertoken);
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      setUsername(decoded.username);
    }
  });

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen((prevState) => !prevState);

  return (
    <nav className="nav-container">
      <Link className="page-title" to="/">
        <i className="fa fa-reddit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p className="nav-title">FakeReddit</p>
      </Link>

      <form className="search-bar-container">
        <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
        <input
          className="search-bar"
          name="search"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      </form>

      <div className="button-container">
        <LoginModal />
        <SignupModal />

        <Dropdown size="sm" isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
          <DropdownToggle caret>
            <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu right>
            <DropdownItem header>MORE STUFF</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Help Center</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem divider />
            {console.log("User Logged In: " + username)}
            {token ? (
              <DropdownItem>Log Out</DropdownItem>
            ) : (
              <DropdownItem>Log In / Sign Up</DropdownItem>
            )}
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

LoginModal.js

```
const LoginModal = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = { username: username, password: password };

    axios
      .post("/login", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem("usertoken", res.data);
        console.log("Returned User" + user.username);
        console.log(res.error_message);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className="nav-button login-button" color="link" onClick={toggle}>
        LOG IN
      </Button>

      <Modal className="auth-modal" isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalHeader className="modal-header" toggle={toggle}>
          Log in
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody className="modal-body">
          <Button color="link" className="google-button">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
            CONTINUE WITH GOOGLE
          </Button>
          <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="input-buttons-wrapper">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="USERNAME"
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="PASSWORD"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              className="modal-login-button"
              color="primary"
              onClick={toggle}
            >
              LOG IN
            </Button>
          </form>
          <p className="go-to-signup">New to FakeReddit? SIGN UP </p>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this question with `Flask`.  This is a good fit for flask:

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome, <a href="/profile">{{ current_user.username }}</a> 
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="/login?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a> 
{% endif %}
```